# Visual Equation Editor to LaTeX Code

Tags: equations, editors

I'm looking for a Windows based visual equation editor which produces LaTeX code.

I need the functionality like in those online equation editors such as the [LaTeX Equation Editor site](http://www.numberempire.com/texequationeditor/equationeditor.php)

It should be an open source/freeware software (Portable installation preferred).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12062/codecogs-like-software-ide-latex-environment

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/)?

See also [this list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/215).

Any reasonably developed LaTeX IDE will have buttons for adding a variety of symbols as in the online one you linked to. For example, [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) and [TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) both have this capacity.

TeXworks doesn't yet seem to have this capacity (at least, the version that comes bundled with Ubuntu's TeXlive 2009 doesn't) but I expect it will soon...

Comment: @Seamus. Thank you. Is there a stand alone program dedicated for this task only?

Comment: @Drazick Not that I know of, but I don't see what task would require one. What do you want to get out of this editor? Do you want _pictures_ of your equations? If so, the [standalone](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone/) package might help. Could you edit your question to explain what it is you want and why you don't want a full IDE...

Comment: There is Inlage, looks nifty but it's not freeware :(

Comment: @Seamus, The computer I'll be using won't have an internet connection. My skills in writing LaTeX are limited, hence I'd like the most comprehensive capability in that area.

Comment: @Drazick and why don't you want a full IDE? What's wrong with using TeXworks or similar?

Comment: TeXWorks doesn't have that capability. I need something which is fully featured. If you have Editor which works with MiKTeX and does it as well, I'll take it. TeXMaker doesn't include Visualizer, just some predefined buttons.

Comment: @Drazick The online equation editor doesn't have "preview" really. You have to click render equation to see the result. TeXworks does pretty much the same thing: you see the result when you compile the document... Look at LyX, it is closer to what you seem to want.

Comment: @Seamus, What I need is the ability to create equation using buttons. Create equation visually. Button for fraction, integral, derivative etc... Something which let me create the LaTeX code from buttons without knowing the language itself. Thanks.

Comment: @Drazick I said in my answer that TeXworks doesn't have this yet. Try LyX or TeXmaker. Each of these has buttons which will allow you to build up the equation. LyX has better immediate previewing.

Comment: Since I don't use LyX I was asking for a standalone program with that capability. Thank you.

Comment: @Drazick I suggest you edit your question to reflect the specifics of your request.

Comment: @Drazick I still don't understand why you just can't use LyX for this. It is free, available on all platforms and has a superb math editor. I use it all the time specifically for this purpose. Just activate the source preview window and you can easily edit your equations in LyX and then Copy&Paste the LaTeX code from the preview window into your LaTeX document. So why do you bother so much that LyX can do more than that? You don't have to use the other stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Not free but [Mathtype](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) lets you draw out equations visually and then copy the equation to LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I found a [web based editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) that allows you to write the equation in LaTeX, and provides some examples to create your own equation. Is not a fully visual tool, but does not require an installation, and will give you different options to export the equation.

Also, you should check the symbols and different options, as it has several templates that you can change for making your equations.

Answer (score 1):

A great online editor is available at [formulasheet.com](http://formulasheet.com/editor.php). It provides a live preview of the formula that you are creating so gives direct visual feedback. It has buttons to press for symbols and constructs like fractions and matrices so you can create the LaTeX code without knowing all LaTeX commands. It runs out of the browser so can work on Windows machines.

It also has additional options such as font, text color, background color, render resolution, and allows you to copy-paste the formula that you created to MS Word 2007+ using MathML.