# Is there an opposite to Detexify website (ie. write the command and it displays the output in LaTeX style)?

Tags: detex

As the title says. Such a website would be very useful to test things out. Thanks.

Comment: ShareLaTeX or OpenLeaf...?

Comment: Thanks! From what i see i have to make an account for both of them. Is there such a website that doesn't require an account?

Comment: you can open up the "comprehensive symbols list" (`texdoc comprehensive`) and use the "find" option in the pdf file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Visual equation editor to LaTeX Code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18155/5764)

Comment: If you click the `symbols` tab in Detexify, you can key in the command and get the output symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'opposite' of Detexify is provided by Detexify itself. Instead of giving your input via drawing (which is the `classify` option), you can also enter in the commands and get the output in symbols instantaneously (which is the `symbols` option).
See below:

**Command -> Symbol (`Symbols` option)**

[image: symbols]

**Drawing -> Commands (`Classify` option)**

[image: classify]

Answer (score 3):

I often make us of http://mathurl.com if I am after a quick preview. I don't believe that you can include any extra packages, so it is limited.

Answer (score 3):

Open `texdoc comprehensive` (some front-ends have a facility for this), look in the index of the PDF document you get on the screen for the command and you'll see its graphical representation(s).

### Start of the document

[image]

### Start of the index

[image]

### Example of index

[image]

You can click on the page number, which is a link to the relevant font table, where you also get information about the needed package.

Answer (score 1):

With [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) you don't need to sign in, just click on the `CREATE A NEW PAPER` button of their home page:

[image]

It appears an example of a document, click on `Source` button if you don't like `Rich Text` and then you can write whatever you want and see it immediately.

[image]